# How to MVC C# Viewmodel to join data from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Can anyone please tell me, I need to MVC C# Viewmodel join data from multiple tables and use chtml page @model ViewModels.StoreBrowseViewModel. But my logic will retrieve only one table data.
This is my class diagram. red box primary key, blue box foreign key

[image: class diagram]

This is my StoreBrowseViewModel class

```
 public class StoreBrowseViewModel
 {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Shape { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Clarity { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public Shape Shapes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Gemstone> Gemstones { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Clarity> Clarites { get; set; }
}
```

This is my action method.

```
 public ActionResult Browse(string gemCategory = "")
 {

  var gemstones = from g in db.Gemstones
                            select g;
var category = db.Categories.Where(p => p.Name == gemCategory).FirstOrDefault();
 gemstones = (gemstones.Include(s => s.Shapes)
                    .Include(c => c.Clarities)
                    .Where(p => p.CategoryID == category.CategoryID)); 
 var viewModel = new StoreBrowseViewModel()            
            {
                Category = category,
                Gemstones = gemstones,
            };
 return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

This is my view model chtml page

```
@model ViewModels.StoreBrowseViewModel
grid.Column("Carat", header: "Weight " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "Carat")@item.Carat),
grid.Column("ShapeId", header: "Shape " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "Shape")@item.Shape),
grid.Column("ClarityId", header: "Clarity " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "Clarity")@item.Clarity),
grid.Column("Price", header: "Price(USD) " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "Price")@item.Price),
```

This is my out put It should display shape name and clarity name

[image: Out Put]

Comment: grid.Column("ShapeName", header: "Shape Name " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "Shape")@item.Shape.Name)

Comment: StoreBrowseViewModel does not have valves Shape Name  and clarity name only id

Comment: It should. That's the whole point of the viewModel. You send whatever data you want.

Comment: This is question I have my view model not pass shape name and clarity name. var viewModel = new StoreBrowseViewModel(). this is my chtml page grid.Column("ShapeId", header: "Shape " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "Shape"))

Comment: If I add Gemstones single table all fields including Shape name and Clarity name, It'll display all in my chtml page.

Comment: If I join tables it'll error @item.Shape.Name {"'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'Shape'"}

Comment: Yes I did SQL manually it worked well and I did linq with list (IEnumerable) it work me. The only issue is I don't know how to use linq without collection @model ViewModels.StoreBrowseViewModel and grid.Column. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it differently from what im gona show below but this should help...

```
public ActionResult Browse(string gemCategory = "")
{
    var category = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == gemCategory);

    var gemstones = db.Gemstones.Include(s => s.Shapes)
                                .Include(c => c.Clarities)
                                .Include(c => c.Categories)
                                .Include(c => c.Cuts)
                                .Include(c => c.Orgins)
                                .Where(p => p.CategoryID == category.CategoryID);

    var viewModel = new StoreBrowseViewModel() {Gemstones = gemstones};

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

view model

```
public class StoreBrowseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Gemstone> Gemstones { get; set; }
}
```

in the view

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Gemstones)
{
    <span>@item.Name</span>

    @foreach(var item2 in Model.Gemstones.Clarities)
    {
        <span>@item2.Name</span>
    }
}
```

Comment: StoreBrowseViewModel has only public IEnumerable<Gemstone> Gemstones { get; set; }

Comment: I am getting @item.Shape.Name it say {"'System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow' does not contain a definition for 'Shape'"}

Comment: It say {"Column \"Shape\" does not exist."} why was that?  grid.Column("Shape", header: "Shape " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "Shape")),